# Is there a Non-Latin "Pseudo-Latin" Font?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

Latin fonts that imitate the appearance of other scripts have been around for a while. Here are a few examples:

[image]

([Link](http://www.dafont.com/samarkan.font)), imitates [Devanagari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari)

[image]

([Link](http://www.dafont.com/alhambra.font)), imitates [Kufic Arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kufic)

[image]

([Link](http://www.dafont.com/manga-style.font)), imitates [Katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana)

This, then, brings me directly to my question: **Does the reverse exist, i.e. is there a non-Latin (e.g. Arabic) font that imitates the appearance of the [Latin script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script)?**

Comment: The whole current Cyrillic alphabet is what you are asking for, not just a single font of it. I don't know when that happened though, because the early versions imitated Greek, not Latin.

Comment: @RumiP.: Cyrillic is *derived* from the Greek uncial script; it does not "imitate" it in any accepted sense of the word (any more than the Latin script imitates Greek; it is merely a descendant of it). That Latin and Cyrillic scripts have a similar appearance reflects their common origin and is not a choice made by the font designer as the examples given in the question are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question. It seems to be some non-latin fonts designed to resemble latin-ish, but in my opinion is very difficult judge whether they resemble latin for all the world cultures or not.

> To be more clear, I'm used to latin characters and for me your examples *could* look like Devanagari, Kufic Arabic and Katakana characters. I'm not so sure that this resemblance exists for the people who natively use those fonts.

Having said this, I've found a few examples and articles on the net:

**[Big Caslon Thai](http://cadsondemak.com/foundry/wallpaper3-%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%8C/)** *seems* to look latin (but you have to ask to a Thai if it looks like latin!):

[image: Big Caslon Thai]

**[Helvetica Thai](http://www.linotype.com/1824-32659/helveticathai.html)** is designed to be similar to Helvetica:

[image: Helvetica Thai]

**[Karmic Sanj](https://www.behance.net/gallery/Karmic-Sanj-GurmukhiPunjabi-Unicode-True-Type-font/9832573)** and [GHW Adhiapak Unicode Gurmukhi](https://www.behance.net/gallery/GHW-Adhiapak-Unicode-GurmukhiPunjabi-font/9795527) are looking like a 180° rotated hand writings:

[image: Karmic Sanj] [image: GHW Adhiapak Unicode Gurmukhi]

[Here](http://typophile.com/node/75290) are examples of **matching Hebrew and Latin**, and if you *rotate* the examples, they are latin looking:

[image: Hebrew rotated]

**Some related links**:

- [There are decorative fonts that mimic the appearance of other writing systems (Chinese, Arabic, Indic, etc.). Are there fonts in other writing systems designed to imitate the appearance of the Latin alphabet?](http://www.reddit.com/r/typography/comments/1s8xjs/there_are_decorative_fonts_that_mimic_the/)
- [Matching Hebrew and Latin](http://typophile.com/node/75290)
- [Miscellaneous Truetype Gurmukhi Fun fonts](http://www.billie.grosse.is-a-geek.com/resources-03h.html)
- [On loops and Latinisation](http://www.fontpad.co.uk/loops-and-latinisation/)